# Update XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I want to replace an XML node that is not a child of the root element. How can I do it - not in .NET 3.5?

I don't know the exact path to the node I want to replace, I get the node by XPath query like:

```
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
oldItem = root.SelectSingleNode("//Node1[@name='aaa']//Node2[Item='bbb']/Value");
```

How can I replace this old item?

Comment: what do you want to replace **exactly**? give a before-after example.

Answer (score 3):

Use `root.SelectSingleNode("query").Value = [New value]`